# I want to print to pdf file in javascript, where outputstream and pdfwriter

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to create a PDF from a server-side controller (report) (ireport) with ajax (and so on), and try to return the data to pdfwriter, servletoutputstream, and httpservletresponse. (I do not know exactly what I'm doing, but I'm doing it this way).

The original purpose was to send a server-side pdf file to the client, find the printer and print without a preview window.

Among them, I wrote 'application / pdf' on the server side and 'datetype: text' on the client side ajax (there is an error if I do not use ajax datatype: text)
If you print the results to the console, they will only be listed as unknown code.

Currently I am trying to put it into an iframe frame.

Question!
1. What should I do to use the text string sent to server -> client as pdf or script code?
(I have already asked you two weeks ago)
2. How do I send a pdf to server -> client? I would like to apply it to the screen by expressing it directly in code instead of downloading it. To print out.

ENG)>
// I used ajax only, because I dont know any other way

```js
$.ajax({
 url : "url",
 data : JSON.stringify(data),
 dataType : "text",
 type: "POST",
 contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
async : false,
success: function(result){
// I want to view PDF contents and directly print to PDF.
}
})
```

```
public Params createIbExItemLabelReport(HttpServletRequest resq, HttpSession session, Params inParams, HttpServletResponse resp) throws Exception{
   Params outParams = ParamsFactory.createParams(inParams);

   resp.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
   resp.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
   resp.setHeader("Expires", "0");

   List<DataRow> list = new ArrayList<DataRow>();
   String reportCd = "15";
   String fileName = "ibExItemLabel"+reportCd+"Report";
   String nullJpgFile = "";

   int flag = 0;
   int nullCheck = 0;
   for(DataRow dr : inParams.getDataTable("dt_data")){

       String imgName = "c:\\WMS\\LABEL\\FIAC021_" +reportCd + ".jpg";

       File f = new File(imgName);
       if (!f.isFile()) {
           flag = 1;
           if(nullCheck != 0){
               nullJpgFile += ", ";
           }
           nullJpgFile += "FIAC021";
           nullCheck++;
           continue;
       }
       String bacodeCd = "FIAC02120180416001";
       dr.setParam("imgName", imgName);
       dr.setParam("bacodeCd", bacodeCd);

       list.add(dr);
   }

   if(flag == 1){
       outParams.setParam("ERROR_FILE", "제품코드 ["+nullJpgFile+"]의 라벨 사이즈" + reportCd + "인 파일이 존재하지않습니다.");
     return outParams;
   }

   String appPath = session.getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
   String pdfPath = null;

   List<DataRow> list2 = new ArrayList<DataRow>();
   for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){

         for(int j = 0; j < list.get(i).getInt("printQty"); j++){
           list2.add(list.get(i));
       }

   }

   Report report = new Report();
   pdfPath = report.reportToPdf(session, list2, fileName);

   outParams.setParam("fileName", pdfPath);

   System.out.println("Found! FileName is ' : "+ pdfPath);
   pdfPath = appPath + pdfPath;
   pdfPath = pdfPath.replace("//", "/");

   ServletOutputStream servletOutput = resp.getOutputStream();

   PdfWriter pdfWriter = null;
   StringBuffer pdfJs = null;
   ByteArrayOutputStream pdfOutput = null;
   InputStream pdfInput = null;
   PdfReader pdfReader = null;
   PdfStamper pdfStamper = null;

   pdfOutput = convertPDFToByteArrayOutputStream(pdfPath);
   int printCopy = 1;
   if (printCopy == 0) {
     printCopy = 1;
   }
   if (printCopy > 1) {
     PdfCopyFields pdfPrintCopy = new PdfCopyFields(pdfOutput);
     for (int i = 0; i < printCopy; i++) {
       pdfPrintCopy.addDocument(new PdfReader(outputToInputStream(pdfOutput)));
     }
     pdfPrintCopy.close();
   }

   pdfInput = outputToInputStream(pdfOutput);
   pdfReader = new PdfReader(pdfInput);

   pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, servletOutput);
   pdfWriter = pdfStamper.getWriter();

   String printerNm = "SINDOH D410 Series PCL";

   pdfWriter.setViewerPreferences(PdfWriter.HideMenubar | PdfWriter.HideToolbar | PdfWriter.HideWindowUI);

   pdfJs = new StringBuffer();
   pdfJs.append("var param=this.getPrintParams();\r");
   pdfJs.append("param.printerName=\"").append(printerNm).append("\";\r");

   pdfJs.append("param.interactive=param.constants.interactionLevel.silent;\r");
   pdfJs.append("param.pageHandling=param.constants.handling.shrink;\r");
   pdfJs.append("this.print(param);\r");
   pdfJs.append("this.closeDoc();");
   pdfWriter.addJavaScript(pdfJs.toString(), false);
   servletOutput.flush();

   Log.debug("servletOutput " );
   if (pdfInput != null) {
       try {
         pdfInput.close();
       } catch (Exception e) {
       }
       pdfInput = null;
     }
     if (pdfOutput != null) {
       try {
         pdfOutput.close();
       } catch (Exception e) {
       }
       pdfOutput = null;
     }
     if (pdfReader != null) {
       pdfReader.close();
       pdfReader = null;
     }
     pdfWriter = null;
     try {
       if (pdfStamper != null) {
         pdfStamper.close();
         pdfStamper = null;
       }
     } catch (Exception e) {
     }
     resp.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename="+pdfPath);
     resp.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf; charset=UTF-8");
     resp.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

     Log.debug("before outParams " );
   return outParams;
    }


   private InputStream outputToInputStream(ByteArrayOutputStream source) {
   return new ByteArrayInputStream(source.toByteArray());
}



private static ByteArrayOutputStream convertPDFToByteArrayOutputStream(String FilePath) {

   InputStream inputStream = null;
   ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
   try {

       inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(FilePath));

       byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
       baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

       int bytesRead;
       while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
           baos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
       }

   } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   } finally {
       if (inputStream != null) {
           try {
               inputStream.close();
           } catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
       }
   }
   return baos;
}
```

please answer my question

Comment: Plz. wait for you answer. But, I accept to completely other style code.